Both XPaths point to the same element, but one throws the error that the element is invisible while the other does not
I wrote the following XPath:
//li[.//span[text()='Owner']]//span[text()='Add']

However, WATIR/Selenium reports that the element is invisible. Interestingly, when I use //span[text()='Add'], it works fine. Both XPaths points to the same span when I am checking via developer tools. What could be causing this discrepancy?

Can you add a HTML/XML document that replicates the behavior?

Without any context, it is not possible to give a proper answer. Please share the error and the HTML of the element.

As others have mentioned we would need to see that actual document being traversed. I understand you believe these to be the same element but the specificity of the first XPath in combination with the issue you have presented suggests that there is another span (anywhere in the document) that has the text "Add" and is visible.

worth noting that text() method will retrieve displayed/rendered text.  So only visible.  These are also text nodes which are sub-nodes of element nodes.
